# MFMailComposeViewController timing out on canSendMail?

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

So the subject is mostly self explanatory. When I step into

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] && [sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Contact Support"])
        [self displaySupportComposerSheet];
    else if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        [self displayDarrenComposerSheet];
```

I get this message in the console: timeout messaging Mail to determine CanSendMail state

I also tried what seems to be the old style of doing the mail compose, which is

```
  Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
```

and I still get the same message. Any ideas?

Also, it did not seem to like it when I made MFMailComposeViewController a property, instead of a local variable to each method, why is that?

Comment: ClassFromString is "old style" because, circa 3.0, the class might not  have been available.  Looking up the class first and checking for nil was a way to detect availability of the service.  You can drop it now.    As an investigation step, can you strip away all the other code and just set a BOOL to the result of canSendMail.  NSLog(@"can send mail = %d", theBool); on the next line.  Put a breakpoint there and run (don't step).  See if you get the console message before you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: In which ios version your are trying??

Comment: This is with iOS 6. I mainly was messing with it because when ever the app is first run and the mail button is first clicked, it lags a bit, most likely due to instantiating MFMailComposeViewController when the method is called, so thats why I started messing with it.

Comment: @terry lewis did You solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when composing a large PDF file to add as an attachment before I called `[[MFMailComposer alloc] init]`.  When I moved the composer creation to a point before the large memory consumption of the PDF creator, I no longer saw this error in the log.